# How to store hex values following 0s into char pointer in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, hex

I am facing an issue with storing hex values that has 0s inbetween.
1) I am getting a string's value in the form of macAddress of size 17.
2) Converting them to hex and storing it as a string of size 6.
When 0s are added inbetween, not able to store it after the 0s. Only the values before 0s are stored.
Below is the sample code written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int hestToMacStr(char **charPtrPtr)
{
    unsigned int mac0, mac1, mac2, mac3, mac4, mac5;
    char *str = *charPtrPtr;

    /* initialize the variables */
    mac0 = mac1 = mac2 = mac3 = mac4 = mac5 = 0;

    sscanf( *charPtrPtr, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &mac0, &mac1, &mac2, &mac3, &mac4, &mac5 );

    str[0] = mac0 & 0xFF;
    str[1] = mac1 & 0xFF;
    str[2] = mac2 & 0xFF;
    str[3] = mac3 & 0xFF;
    str[4] = mac4 & 0xFF;
    str[5] = mac5 & 0xFF;
    str[6] = '\0';
    printf("charPtrPtr: %s, str: %s, mac: %x,%x,%x,%x,%x,%x\n", *charPtrPtr, str, str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5]);
}

int main()
{
    char *haystack = ( char * ) malloc (18);
    int i = 0;

    sprintf(haystack,"66:66:66:00:66:66"); //code1
    sprintf(haystack,"66:66:66:66:66:66"); //code2
    hestToMacStr(&haystack);
    printf("haystack: %s, Mac: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", haystack, haystack[0], haystack[1], haystack[2], haystack[3], haystack[4], haystack[5]);

    free(haystack);

    return(0);
}
Output1: 
charPtrPtr: fff, str: fff, mac: 66,66,66,0,66,66
haystack: fff, Mac: 66:66:66:00:66:66

Output2: 
charPtrPtr: ffffff, str: ffffff, mac: 66,66,66,66,66,66
haystack: ffffff, Mac: 66:66:66:66:66:66
```

output1 is for code1 and output2 is for code2.
The expected output1 is: fff0ff for code1. Anybody please help me by guiding how can I store all the values to my charPtr.

Thanks, Denise

Comment: _Converting them to hex and storing it as a string of size 6_... You can't. Minimum required chars for that kind of string are 13. While you can store values in 6 bytes but not print the as string....as you are facing...

Comment: '\0' is a termination character for a string, you should create a data structure containing a `pointer to uint8_t` and it's `size` or any other structure suiting your needs. Anyways this is not an input for a string anymore

Comment: I cannot do that because this field is defined in the database as char array of size 6 @pbn

Comment: @LPs When I try getting it from the stored place, I was not able to get all the stored values, from the calling place. I dont wanna print it but how can I confirm if all the chars are stored??

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour. `%x` expects n `unsiogned int`, you pass `signed int` due to integer promotions.

Comment: I think hex can also be printed using %x. Will this be invoking undefined behaviour? I never seen. @Olaf

Comment: I did not say it is about the output format. It is the argument. If you don't understnand my comment, please do some research. These are fundamental concepts of C.

Comment: @Denise-- note that `unsigned int` and `signed int` (or just `int`) have nothing to do with hexadecimal, decimal, etc.; `%x` is called a _conversion specifier_ because it tells `printf()` and friends to convert the binary representation of a value to a printable hexadecimal representation. And, as [@Olaf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073288/how-to-store-hex-values-following-0s-into-char-pointer-in-c#comment73231018_43073288) mentioned, `%x` expects an `unsigned int`.